# How to do both Conditional INSERT and UPDATE on DUPLICATE in mySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to insert a record into mySQL table_1 (`product_family`) only when `product_technology_name` exists in table_2 (`product_technology`). `product_technology_key` (Corresponding **primary key** in `product_technology` table for `prod_technology_name`) is the foreign key in table_1 and has to be written in to table_1 with the record. If the table_1 '`product_family_name`' (**unique field**) name does exists in the table, it should be updated. The following query is what I tried in [mySQL WorkBench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), but I get the following error.

> "Unknown column 'prod_technology_key' in 'field list' 0.016
> sec"

MySQL Script :

```
SET @Param1 = "MTL";
SET @Param2 = "MTL description";
SET @Param3 = "MTL";

INSERT INTO product_family (
                        prod_family_technology_key,
                        prod_family_name,
                        prod_description
                        ) 
                    SELECT (
                        prod_technology_key,
                        @Param1,
                        @Param2
                        )
                    WHERE (SELECT prod_technology_key FROM product_technology WHERE prod_technology_name = @Param3)
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                        prod_family_name = @Param1,
                        prod_description = @Param2;
```

Comment: You'll need a `FROM` clause in your `SELECT` if you refer to any columns of the table. When you use `INSERT...SELECT`, there is no implicit table in the `SELECT`. It's like a standalone query.

Comment: Yes, It's working if  all the fields are coming from the 'product_technology' table. BUt here I have two additional vales (Param1 and Param2).

Comment: You can put constant expressions into a select-list. By the way, remove the parentheses around your select-list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected script :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO product_family (
                        prod_family_technology_key,
                        prod_family_name,
                        prod_description
                        )
                    SELECT prod_technology_key, @Param1, @Param2
                    FROM product_technology WHERE prod_technology_name = @Param3
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                        prod_family_name = @Param1,
                        prod_description = @Param2;
```